# linq as dataset issue with column names

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

How can I avoid using magic strings in a LINQ query against a datatable?

This works:

```
public IEnumerable getDisplayNames()
{
    IEnumerable nameQry =
        from row in displayTable.AsEnumerable()
        select row.Field("display");

    return nameQry;
}
```

but this fails with "Specified cast is not valid.":

```
public IEnumerable getDisplayNames()
{
    string disp = myDictionary["D"];

    IEnumerable nameQry =
        from row in displayTable.AsEnumerable()
        select row.Field(disp);

    return nameQry;
}
```

My preference is to use a local string (or a direct reference off of myDictionary) instead of hard coding the strings in place.  So I want to use the string disp instead of the phrase "display" in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetTheRows(DataTable dt, string name)
{
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("yourColumn") == name);
}
```

or whatever the correct data type is in your given scenario.  You need to specify the type when using the `Field<T>` method.